# How to bypass postfix milters for certain users?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, perl, milter

I am trying to set up an incoming MTA server using Postfix. I have specific requirements that some users' emails should not go through the milters. Is there any way this can be done in Postfix? One way I think is by editing the milters but that will be a larger task, so just like there can be whitelist tables for access checks is it possible some recipients can be skipped from the milters? Another way I can think of is by using header_checks and using a separate smtp process but I am not able to implement it.

Comment: Setup a second Postfix server with the desired config. Migrate the users there. Tell them to update their configs.

Answer (score 1):

No and this is impossible in principle; this is not specific to Postfix.

Milter is basically [a collection of functions](https://pythonhosted.org/pymilter/milter_api/api.html) that are called on corresponding stages of SMTP session: one is called when client connects, next one is called when it issues HELO/EHLO, next one when issues MAIL FROM, and so on; but you can't probably know who'll be the recipient until the client issues RCPT TO command. So, in your case, milters inherently have to run *before* you're able to determine whether to run them or not, which is logical nonsense.

In addition to this, a single SMTP session might specify more than one recipient, if the client issues several RCPT TO commands during the session. It is unclear what to do in this case when policies for different recipients differ.

This is not even unique to milters; *any* mail filtering starts happening right when connection is received by the server, but the recipient-based decision could be made only after RCPT TO. Postfix may delay rejection *notification* until after RCPT TO is received, but even in that case internally it might *decide* to reject earlier. Only the notification will be delayed and not the restriction lists processing and decisions. But here you at least can set up restriction lists so not to reject anything on early stages. This is not what you can readily do with milters.

The best you can do here about milter is to develop a *proxy milter* application which does nothing on early session stages, and proxies calls to some real milter on later stages. Be aware that many real milters *expect* their component functions to be called in the specific order, and might behave incorrectly if you call, say, their xxfi_envrcpt for a session where xxfi_connect wasn't called. So your proxy milter should stack these early calls and just flush them into real milter after all xxfi_envrcpt calls are made and it can decide that "milters should run".

I heard nothing about such ready-made proxy milter soultion; probably, because nobody in the right mind might ever need such an obscure piece of software. That you think you need this makes me think that you probably don't fully understand how e-mail technology works, what is it for and how to secure it properly.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding but I meant smtpd milters (not policyd services  or restrictions). They are applied after the restriction classes. As per applicability of header_checks method I think it's feasible if I place these milters as content filter. And I donot what to bypass filter per recipient but on basis of 'Mail From' domain.

Comment: I am talking exactly about smtpd milters. If you read MILTER_README it explains when it is called — in each session stage, right after postfix's restrictions lists were processed for that stage, if message is not rejected yet. Again, **milters inherently can not be selectively called**, either you have them processing all your connections or none (not using milters at all). Don't compare them with header_checks or whatever, because header_checks only get called on DATA stage, while milters are called after each one, starting with connect.